# the following functions might not be defined at runtime: lsp-format-buffer, lsp-organize-imports function ‘dap-go-setup’ is not known to be defined

Tags: debugging, lsp-mode, golang, lsp

I 've below emacs init file config setup

I'm getting below error in the emacs startup. I don't know what might be the root cause of the issue

> the following functions might not be defined at runtime: lsp-format-buffer, lsp-organize-imports
> the function ‘dap-go-setup’ is not known to be defined.

The emacs file is  -

`~/.emacs.d/init.el` file is

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)

(package-initialize)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
            '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)

(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
(package-refresh-contents)
(package-install 'use-package))

(require 'use-package)


(load "~/.emacs.d/golang.el")
```

My `~/.emacs.d/golang.el` file is -

```
(use-package lsp-mode
:ensure t
:commands (lsp lsp-deferred)
:hook (go-mode . lsp-deferred))

;; Set up before-save hooks to format buffer and add/delete imports.
;; Make sure you don't have other gofmt/goimports hooks enabled.
(defun lsp-go-install-save-hooks ()
(add-hook 'before-save-hook #'lsp-format-buffer t t)
(add-hook 'before-save-hook #'lsp-organize-imports t t))
(add-hook 'go-mode-hook #'lsp-go-install-save-hooks)

;; Optional - provides fancier overlays.
(use-package lsp-ui
:ensure t
:commands lsp-ui-mode
:init)

;; Company mode is a standard completion package that works well with lsp-mode.
(use-package company
:ensure t
:config
;; Optionally enable completion-as-you-type behavior.
(setq company-idle-delay 0)
(setq company-minimum-prefix-length 1))

(use-package company-lsp
:ensure t
:commands company-lsp)

;; Optional - provides snippet support.
(use-package yasnippet
:ensure t
:commands yas-minor-mode
:hook (go-mode . yas-minor-mode))

(use-package dap-mode
;;:custom
;;(dap-go-debug-program `("node" "~/extension/out/src/debugAdapter/goDebug.js"))
:config
(dap-mode 1)
(setq dap-print-io t)
;;(setq fit-window-to-buffer-horizontally t)
;;(setq window-resize-pixelwise t)
(require 'dap-hydra)
(require 'dap-go)       ; download and expand vscode-go-extenstion to the =~/.extensions/go=
(dap-go-setup)
(use-package dap-ui
    :ensure nil
    :config
    (dap-ui-mode 1)
    )
)

(use-package flycheck-golangci-lint
:ensure t)

(setq lsp-ui-doc-enable nil
    lsp-ui-peek-enable t
    lsp-ui-sideline-enable t
    lsp-ui-imenu-enable t
    lsp-ui-flycheck-enable t)


(setq lsp-gopls-staticcheck t)
(setq lsp-eldoc-render-all t)
(setq lsp-gopls-complete-unimported t)
```

My operating system is -

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: ManjaroLinux
Description:    Manjaro Linux
Release:    20.2
Codename:   Nibia
```

What is the root cause of this issue?

Comment: It's not an error message. It's a warning. Where/when are you seeing it? Do you see it as a byte-compiler warning? Are you byte-compiling your init file (don't bother)?

Answer (score 0):

Add `:commands` entries for the relevant functions.

```
(use-package lsp-mode
:ensure t
:commands (lsp lsp-deferred lsp-format-buffer lsp-organize-imports)
:hook (go-mode . lsp-deferred))

(use-package dap-mode
:commands dap-go-setup ; I think :functions will also work
:config
(dap-mode 1)
(setq dap-print-io t)
(require 'dap-hydra)
(require 'dap-go) ; download and expand vscode-go-extenstion to the =~/.extensions/go=
(dap-go-setup)
(use-package dap-ui
    :ensure nil
    :config
    (dap-ui-mode 1)
    ))
```